# NotReadablePropertyException in spring + jsp + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop a spring application to display the employees in table and on selection of a radio button, the filtered result should be displayed in the same table (same jsp). i tried below, but getting NotReadablePropertyException. Please help.

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    /** Service object to handle web request */
    @Autowired
    protected EmployeeService empService;

    /**
     * This method will form the list of employees and return the string to be
     * used for spring to fetch the appropriate JSP
     * 
     * @param model
     *            - Spring Model class object
     * @return String - to be used to help spring to fetch the appropriate JSP
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployees(Model model) {
        List<EmployeeDetails> empList = empService.getEmployeeList();
        model.addAttribute("employees", empList);
        return "employees";
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/filteremployees", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getFilteredData(
            @ModelAttribute("salaryFilterBean") SalaryFilterBean salaryFilterBean) {
        System.out.println("Inside controller to filter data");
        List<EmployeeDetails> filteredEmpList = empService
                .getFilteredEmployeeListBySalary(salaryFilterBean
                        .getFilteremployees());
        System.out.println("filtered data of employee ::: "
                + filteredEmpList.get(0).getEmpSalary());
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("employees");
        model.addObject("employees", filteredEmpList);
        model.addObject("salaryFilterBean", new SalaryFilterBean());
        return model;
    }
}
```

**SalaryFilterBean.java**

```
public class SalaryFilterBean {

    private String filteremployees = null;

    /**
     * @return the filteremployees
     */
    public String getFilteremployees() {
        return filteremployees;
    }

    /**
     * @param filteremployees
     *            the filteremployees to set
     */
    public void setFilteremployees(String filteremployees) {
        this.filteremployees = filteremployees;
    }

}
```

**employees.jsp**

```
<!DOCtype html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf8"
    pageEncoding="utf8"%>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all"
    href="<c:url value="/WEB_INF/css/site.css"/>">
<title>Employee Details</title>
</head>
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById("filterForm").submit();
    }
</script>
<body>
<form:form id="filterForm" modelAttribute="salaryFilterBean"
    action="/filteremployees" method="post" commandName="employees">
    <form:radiobutton path="filteremployees" value="< 10000"
        onclick="submitForm()" /> Salary < 10000
    <form:radiobutton path="filteremployees" value="< 20000"
        onclick="submitForm()" /> Salary < 20000
    <form:radiobutton path="filteremployees" value="> 40000"
        onclick="submitForm()" /> Salary < 20000
</form:form>
<BR>
<table border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">
    <tr>
        <th border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">Id</th>
        <th border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">Name</th>
        <th border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">Date of birth</th>
        <th border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">Experience
        (Years)</th>
        <th border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
        <tr>
            <td border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">${employee.empId}</td>
            <td border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">${employee.empName}</td>
            <td border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">${employee.empDob}</td>
            <td border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">${employee.empYoe}</td>
            <td border="0" style="border: 1px #000000 solid">${employee.empSalary}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**stacktrace:**

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'filteremployees' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'filteremployees' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:699)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.employees_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fradiobutton_005f0(employees_jsp.java:212)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.employees_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(employees_jsp.java:166)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.employees_jsp._jspService(employees_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Where am i going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue.

In commandName in the form tag, the value should be bean class name. Spring will map this commandName value with the bean classes of the project.

**Fix:**

```
<form:form id="filterForm" modelAttribute="salaryFilterBean"
    action="/filteremployees" method="post" commandName="salaryFilterBean">
    <form:radiobutton path="filteremployees" value="< 10000"
        onclick="submitForm()" /> Salary < 10000
    <form:radiobutton path="filteremployees" value="< 20000"
        onclick="submitForm()" /> Salary < 20000
    <form:radiobutton path="filteremployees" value="> 40000"
        onclick="submitForm()" /> Salary < 20000
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
commandName="employees"
```

your commandName is set to employees which is

```
 model.addObject("employees", filteredEmpList);
```

which is

```
 List<EmployeeDetails> filteredEmpList
```

and you are trying to bind

```
<form:radiobutton path="filteremployees" value="< 10000"
        onclick="submitForm()" /> Salary < 10000
```

to it

so it is not able to find `setFilteremployees()` method on `filteredEmpList`

Comment: Thank you.. It has given been some sprak to resolve the problem.